# Would running a certain script every minute via cron be detrimental to anything?

Tags: linux, chmod, system-administration, ubuntu-server

This gets run every minute:

```
cd /var/www/html/[redacted] && find . -exec touch -a -m -t 200001010000.00 {} \;
tac /log/[redacted] > /var/www/html/[redacted]
chmod 775 -R /var/www/
chown www-data:webadmins -R /var/www/
exit 0
```

I feel like that's bad, but I don't really know.

Comment: please don't drive-by downvote!

Comment: You can have `find` filter out files that don't need to be touched, using `-newermt date_string`, and `-not -newermt` to bracket to a 1 sec window or something.  **Also** `touch` can take multiple file arguments, so you can reduce the amount of process-startup overhead by a huge factor by using GNU `find`'s `find \( -newerXY ...  -not -newerXY ... \)  -exec touch ... {} +`.  Note the `+` instead of `\;`.  It's like xargs, but built into find.  This will make it a lot cheaper, esp. if you avoid having chmod and chown do any disk writes when no change is needed, but it still seems silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be changing quite a bit of inodes every minute and generating I/O due to the concatenations. So I think it all depends on the number of files/dirs being operated on.